# Why JMeter hangs on 77000 samples count in summary report?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

Why JMmeter hangs if we set:

- 300 threads
- 600 ramp up time
- one hour duration

In summary report JMeter hangs on 77000 samples count.

Comment: any feedback on answer ?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using GUI Mode for Load Testing, you shouldn't , see:

- http://www.ubik-ingenierie.com/blog/jmeter_performance_tuning_tips/
- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html

Another possible cause is your server hanging, so add a Connection and Response Timeout in Http Request so that it fails when the server hangs instead of waiting infinitely for a response